# How to best update while loop for finding the digital root?

Tags: python, loops

I am attempting to make a function to iterate over digits of some number and find the sum of its digits repeatedly until there is just one digit left in the number.

I wanted to do this with a while loop, but the loop never ends. I don't understand why my update line         n_s = str(total) is not working

```
def digital_root(n):
    n_s = str(n)
    
    total = 0
    
    while len(n_s) != 1:
        for digit in n_s:
            total += int(digit)
        n_s = str(total)
    return total
```

Answer (score 0):

You aren't resetting the value of `total`, so the value from the last loop is being used, rather than starting from 0.

```
def digital_root(n):
    n_s = str(n)

    while len(n_s) != 1:
        total = 0
        for digit in n_s:
            total += int(digit)
        n_s = str(total)
    return total
```